# What is the proper way to refer to a given Stack Exchange Network Site?

Tags: discussion, terminology

One of the problems I've encountered is how to refer to a given site within the Stack Exchange network. Of course, each site has its own name, but what if I want to use a non-specific place holder?

"Site" is a bit ambiguous, as it could also be referring to yahoo.com or google.com. "Stack Exchange site" is also ambiguous, because I could be referring to any Stack Exchange network site, or the entirety of the Stack Exchange Network. Is there an accepted way of referring to an arbitrary Stack Exchange Site that isn't so tedious to type?

Comment: I think "site" is fine...

Comment: site and network, don't know who would get confused by singular and group nouns there

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, and you could say "Q/A".

Comment: I don't see the problem with just saying "site" or "SE site" when you don't what to use the actual name, but, if it's clear that you're referring to one of the sites in the StackExchange network, why not use the word `stack`, as in **Stack**Exchange? Then, though technically incorrect for the larger stacks, when you want to refer to an unnamed stack in the network  you could use URL type names:  `stack.SE` and `stack.meta.SE`. The meta sites have switched their URLs, and many may not have noticed, so you could probably even get away with `meta.stack.SE`.